# iOS Facebook SDK - Opening link to users profile works in Safari, but not if user has Facebook app installed on their phone

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

I've setup the Facebook SDK with my current iOS application in which I can login and retrieve the current user's `facebookUID` and other profile information.

I'm currently trying to set it up, so a user can open up another user's Facebook profile from within my app, however, I'm noticing that if the user has the Facebook app already installed on their phone, the request will open up the Facebook app and it will then result in `The page your requested was not found` error.

[image]

However, if the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed on their phone, it will then open up the person's profile correctly in Safari for some reason.

Any ideas what's going on?

Here's how I'm currently trying to open the person's profile:

```
let fbURLWeb: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/\(facebookUID)")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbURLWeb)
```

Also, has anyone gotten this to work in the new SDK, or could this be a bug?

Thanks in advance!